# Eclipse Java Editor line wrapping not as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, formatter

I have following lines of code that just don't want to be wrapped:

```
        tran = TransactionFactory.generateDoubleEntryTransaction(cAcc, acc, qTran.amount, qTran.date, qTran.memo, qTran.payee, qTran.number);
        logger.info("Different currencies, Credit: " + entry.getCreditAmount() + " " + creditCurrency.getSymbol() + " -> " + entry.getDebitAmount() + " " + debitCurrency.getSymbol());
```

Both lines are 150 respective 190 chars long. In my Code formatting settings the maximum line length is set to 100, the Line wrapping settings for Function Calls are all set to "Wrap when necessary". In the preview pane at least it looks like right. Just it doesn't wrap.

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2 here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Formatting doesn't happen automatically, thank god. You have to trigger it with either the shortcut above, or through the menu.

Comment: I know HOW I can trigger the Formatter, I just want to know why it doesn't wrap these lines when I trigger it, and which setting is responsible for that.

Comment: You didn't indicate that. And it works for me with all default configurations.